# IoC container for Portable Class Libraries

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Is there any IoC container out there which supports (or can be made to) the [Portable Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) yet?

I fiddled around with some (SimpleInjector, AutoFac) but they always had one dependency or another which prevented me from using them as a portable class library.

I'm fairly new to the topic so I maybe totally on the wrong track here.

**In more detail:**

I want to create a library containing my models (and later viewmodels) for a MMVM app which should run on .Net 4.5, WP7 and WinRT. This models should be saveable as files. Since the implementation of the particular save algorithms (desktop filesystem, isolated storage) is specific to every platform I hoped to utilize an IoC container to decouple it from the models themselves.

Comment: [This guys](http://blog.schuager.com/2011/01/compactcontainer-rebump.html) has ported Castle Windsor and compared it with his own container.  Not sure if this what you need though.

Comment: Why do you need this? A library should never have to rely on a DI Container in the first place. Only applications should consume DI Containers.

Comment: @MarkSeemann I tried to clarify this in the question. Maybe I'm running in the wrong direction here.

Comment: You don't need a container for that. Just inject the I/O services into their consumers through the constructors.

Comment: @MarkSeemann You are right of course. (+1) I don't need one but I'm intrigued by the concept and if it can be utilized by a portable class library nonetheless. I'll take your advice to get started but think the question is still valid.

Comment: Good points, but as the scope of what can be made portable in .NET keeps expanding, more scenarios for this do show up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe there is a beta of autofac for portable libraries: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/downloads/detail?name=Autofac-2.6.1.841-Portable.zip

Comment: Indeed there is. Thank you for the link.